# Keyboard on iPad defaulting to ASCII

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

I am using a Decimal Pad keyboard on an iPhone application.
I am unable to bring up the same keyboard on the iPad.

I created a new Universal Master-Detail application with one text field - setting the keyboard type in Interface Builder to Decimal Pad - in both storyboards. I didn't do any coding. I ran the app. On the iPhone, I get the Decimal Pad. On the iPad, I always get the ASCII keyboard no matter which keyboard I choose.

I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no decimal pad on the iPad. Because the users will be able to enter letters and not just numbers, you may want to add some input validation for the iPad.

See also:

- [Objective-C: Numbers only text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809609/objective-c-numbers-only-text-field)
- [Which UIKeyboardType can I use on the iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654101/which-uikeyboardtype-can-i-use-on-the-ipad)